# How to take into account uncertainty on number of events

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, parameter-estimation

Suppose I generate a set of events $X_{i}$ for $i = 1,2 \dots N$ and suppose every event is either a success or a failure, ie. $X_{i} = 0, 1$. If $N$ is fixed, the MLE for the probability of success is just $$\hat{p} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_{i}$$ and the variance of the MLE can be estimated as $$V(\hat{p}) = \frac{\hat{p}(1 - \hat{p})}N.$$ But now suppose that $$N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_N),$$ where $\lambda_{N}$ is fairly large, so if we need to, this could be approximated as $$N \sim \text{Normal}\left(\mu = \lambda_{N}, \sigma^2 = \lambda_{N}\right).$$ The MLE is still just $$\hat{p} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_{i}$$ but the variance is increased. What I want to know is how to calculate the new variance of $\hat{p}$ by taking into account the uncertainty on $N$. I tried some error propagation on $N$ but I can't quite reproduce numerical results.

Comment: Have you tried a decomposition of variance (conditioning by $N$) ?

Comment: @Augustin No, I don't think I've heard of that method.

Comment: For me, this is not so much a problem on the variance of a random sum of random variables as it is an illustration of a randomly filtered Poisson process. See NOTE in my answer.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question previous to the last edit. I now believe that your question is asking for the variance of $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k$. Is that correct? I have amended my answer to cover this case, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for the variance of 'a random sum of random variables' is
given in many probability texts. It is derived by conditioning as
suggested by @Augustin. If $X_i, \dots, X_N$ are iid and $N$ is
independent of the $X$'s, then the sum $S$ has variance
$$V(S) = E(N)V(X) + V(N)[E(X)]^2.$$
Roughly speaking, the second term expresses the additional variability due to
random $N$ as compared with fixed $n$. As you might expect,
$E(S) = E(N)E(X).$

Notice the units in the formula for $V(S).$ Terms for $N$ are
pure numbers. Terms for $X$ have squared units to match units
of $S$.

In many cases, a normal approximation for $S$ gives good results.
If the $X$'s are binomial, as in your case, normal approximation
should work fairly well if $E(N)$ is moderately large. (But I would not trust it if $X$'s are extremely skewed with long tails, as for exponential, unless $E(N)$ is large.)

In practical cases, simulation is an easily programmed option--if only as a check
on the accuracy of a normal approximation. (Depending on the
language used, you might have to make explicit accommodation for cases
where $N = 0$.)

Here is a simulation in R of 100,000 experiments with $N \sim Pois(10)$
and $X_i \sim Binom(1, 1/2) = Bernoulli(1/2).$ As the histogram
shows, the normal fit is not excellent because the Poisson
mean is relatively small.

**NOTE:** The dark dots atop the histogram bars are for $Pois(5)$,
which is the **exact** distribution of $S$ in this particular
case. Here $S$ is simply $N$ with half of its realizations
filtered out at random. This result can be established
analytically using moment generating functions. (Imagine thin
lead foil blocking half of the particles emitted from a chunk
of uranium. What gets through is still Poisson.)

```
 m = 10^5;  s = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
   n = rpois(1, 10)
   s[i] = sum(rbinom(n, 1, .5)) }
 mean(s);  sd(s)
 ##  4.99118  # approx E(S) = 5
 ##  2.231150 # approx SD(S), where V(S) = 5
 sqrt(10*.25 + 10*.25)
 ##  2.236068 # exact SD(S)

 mean(s < 5)
 ## 0.4425    # simulated P(S < 5)
 pnorm(4.5, 5, sqrt(5))
 ## 0.4115316 # norm approx P(S < 5)
```

[image]

ADDENDUM: OP seems interested in the distribution of $S/N$ (see Comments). Here is histogram from code slightly altered to retain
values of both $S$ and $N$ at each iteration.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks. One thing that seems to be true numerically is that the variance of the sample mean seems to be the same whether or not I take a fixed amount $\lambda$ samples or if I take $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ samples. They both seem to be equal to $p(1 - p)/\lambda$, where $p$ is the probability that $X_{i}$ is $1$. It seems like since $S \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda p)$ and $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ that $S/N \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$, but that can't be right can it?

Comment: Actually, not $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$, more like $\text{Normal}(\mu = p, \sigma^2 = p(1 - p)/\lambda)$.

Comment: First comment not right: $S/N$ is in $[0, 1]$ and rarely 0 or 1; $Bern(p)$ is either 0 or 1. Some confusion somewhere, but can't track it from what you say. Maybe mixing up dist'n of $\hat p$ with with something else? Your 2nd comment seems better, approx Beta maybe, but can't be normal and restricted to closed unit interval. Also $S/N$ is discrete. Looking for another answer to your original Question?

Comment: First comment not right: $S/N$ is in $[0,1]$ and rarely 0 or 1; $Bern(p)$ is either 0 or 1. Some confusion somewhere, but can't track it from what you say. Maybe mixing up dist'n of $p^$ with with something else? Your 2nd comment seems better, approx Beta maybe, but can't be normal and restricted to closed unit interval. Also $S/N$ is discrete. Appending histogram of simulated $S/N.$ Looking for another answer to your original Question?

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted to know, thanks again!

Comment: Good! Mon plaisir! Just remember simulation results are not proofs. They can suggest what's worth trying to prove. They can show what obviously false. They can suffice for certain real-life applications. But not for formal proof. I don't know your reason for asking or the level of mathematical rigor required. You're on your own with that.Finally, don't overlook the NOTE.

Answer (score 0):

**Variance of the Sum of $\boldsymbol{n}$ Items Where $\boldsymbol{n}$ is Variable**

To complete the discussion, I think it would be nice to include a derivation of the formula for the variance where $n$ is variable, for those that do not have access to an appropriate text.
$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$

For a fixed $n$, we have
$$
\E\!\left[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]=n\E[X]\tag{1}
$$
and, using $\Var[X]=\E\!\left[X^2\right]-\E[X]^2$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\E\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right)^2\right]
&=n\E\!\left[X^2\right]+(n^2-n)\E[X]^2\\
&=n\Var[X]+n^2\E[X]^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the expectation of $(1)$ in $n$ yields
$$
\E\!\left[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]=\E[n]\E[X]\tag{3}
$$
and, using the fact that $\E\!\left[n^2\right]=\Var[n]+\E[n]^2$, taking the expectation of $(2)$ in $n$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\E\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right)^2\right]
&=\E[n]\Var[X]+\E\!\left[n^2\right]\E[X]^2\\
&=\E[n]\Var[X]+\Var[n]\E[X]^2+\E[n]^2\E[X]^2\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]
&=\E\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right)^2\right]-\E\!\left[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]^2\\[6pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\E[n]\Var[X]+\Var[n]\E[X]^2}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Variance of the Mean of $\boldsymbol{n}$ Items Where $\boldsymbol{n}$ is Variable**

I think I misunderstood the question before the last edit. It appears that you are looking for the variance of $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k$ where $n$ is variable. If that is the case, we can follow the same approach as above:

For a fixed $n$, we have
$$
\E\!\left[\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]=\E[X]\tag{6}
$$
and, using $\Var[X]=\E\!\left[X^2\right]-\E[X]^2$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\E\left[\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right)^2\right]
&=\frac1n\E\!\left[X^2\right]+\left(1-\frac1n\right)\E[X]^2\\
&=\frac1n\Var[X]+\E[X]^2\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the expectation of $(6)$ in $n$ yields
$$
\E\!\left[\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]=\E[X]\tag{8}
$$
and taking the expectation of $(7)$ in $n$ gives
$$
\E\left[\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right)^2\right]
=\E\!\left[\frac1n\right]\Var[X]+\E[X]^2\tag{9}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}\!\left[\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]
&=\E\left[\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right)^2\right]-\E\!\left[\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]^2\\[6pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\E\!\left[\frac1n\right]\Var[X]}\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
Note that by Cauchy-Schwarz, we have
$$
\E\!\left[\frac1n\right]\ge\frac1{\E[n]}\tag{11}
$$
Since a Poisson distribution allows $n=0$ and the mean of $0$ items is not well-defined, we will let $n-1$ have a Poisson distribution with mean $N-1$ so that we still have $\mathrm{E}[n]=N$.
$$
\begin{align}
\E\!\left[\frac1n\right]
&=e^{-N+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(N-1)^k}{(k+1)\,k!}\\
&=\frac{e^{-N+1}}{N-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(N-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\\
&=\frac{1-e^{-N+1}}{N-1}\\[6pt]
&\sim\frac1{N-1}\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$